# Why do I get a 'value too great for base' error in my Bash script, but not in the interactive shell?

Tags: bash

[EDIT]
Bad question, caused by a typo, you probably won't learn anything as the answer is specific. It helped my anyway, so thanks to the community. I don't delete it as :
https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question
[/EDIT]

I want to check if a string is the key of a associative array.

This string value depends on some external conditions, I cannot know what it would be.

I read a lot of comment suggesting that my problem resides with an octal or mathematical expression, but I fail to see how (is it possible that my variable resolves as a division, because it contains slahes ?)

This is my array declaration :

`declare -A TARGETS=( [mystring1]=mystring [otherstring1]=otherstring [lastone]=lastone )`

In the script, I get an argument and assign it to a variable (I have to remove quotes from this value because of non-relevant bug):

`DB=$(sed -e "s/^'//" -e "s/'$//" <<<"$3")`

And this is how I make my test. I want to execute something different depending on whether the variable is key of `TARGETS` array.

```
if [ -z "${TARGETS[$DB]}" ]; then
  # shellcheck disable=SC2154
  for URI in "${TARGETS[@]}"
  do
    do_update
  done
else
  URI="${DB}"
  do_update
fi
```

In a case, the value of the DB variable is tags/06/02/2023T105941 and this is how the script ends :

`line 40: tags/06/02/2023T105941: value too great for base (error token is "2023T105941")`

Line 40 in the script is: `if [ -z "${TARGETS[$DB]}" ]; then`

Also, the `do_update` function does not use the `$DB` variable but only the `$URI` value from the loop: `for URI in "${TARGETS[@]}"` or in the else condition `URI="${DB}"`

Funny thing is, if I do something most alike in an interactive shell, on the same machine, the test works :

```
declare -A TARGETS=( [mystring1]=mystring [otherstring1]=otherstring [lastone]=lastone )
DB=tags/06/02/2023T105941
if [ -z "${TARGETS[$DB]}" ]; then echo "fifi"; else echo "lolo"; fi;
```

return fifi without any issue.

What did I get wrong ?

Comment: Which one is line 40? You appear to be using the value in an arithmetic context, and it thinks you are trying to divide by (say) a base-36 number (due to the "digit" `T`).

Comment: ... and I don't see any arithmetic context in the code posted.  Does the issue perhaps arise in the `do_update` function?

Comment: Side note: you don't need to launch a whole `sed` process just to remove leading and trailing quotes from one variable's value.  This would do: `DB=${3#\'}; DB=${DB%\'}`.

Comment: I edited my question to answer yours the best I could (line 40 and precisions about the do_update function. I fail to see where there is a arithmetic computation in this script, but surely, there must be

Comment: The error is consistent with `TARGETS` being a normal array, not associative. You would have to post an [MCVE]. You could try `"${TARGETS["$DB"]}"`

Comment: I built a script with your array declaration, sed line and posted if-then-else.  And I gave it a third argument == `tags/06/02/2023T105941`.  I also added a couple echo to see what it was doing.  I get no error.  I would guess the issue is within do_update based on what you have given us.  See [mcve].

Comment: You mention do_update does not use $DB, it uses $URI.  But URI is built from $DB in th else case, so your ` tags/06/02/2023T105941` can get to do_update.  And you tried  the if-then-else without do_update and it worked, so...

Answer (score 1):

@KamilCuk pointed me in the right direction : "The error is consistent with TARGETS being a normal array, not associative".

I double-checked the array declaration (which are situated in a variety of location) and some of them were missing the `-A` declaration.

Also, I use the syntax `if [ -z "${TARGETS["$DB"]}" ]; then` to ensure that the value of $DB is treated as a string key rather than a numerical value.

It was mostly a bug between the chair and the keyboard, as often.

Thanks.

Comment: Questions caused by typos can just be closed/deleted; answers should be added when they're likely to be helpful to others encountering the same error (and the more common reason to get "value too great for base" in bash is something different: numbers like `08` being parsed as octal, in which only 0-7 are legal; so this is an unusual case that might lead folks searching on the topic away from answers to the more likely cause).

Comment: To avoid type confusion like this, I'd recommend putting `declare -A TARGETS` near the beginning of the script (before the various conditionals that lead to assignments to it), then just using plain assignments to it (e.g. `TARGETS=( [mystring1]=mystring [otherstring1]=otherstring [lastone]=lastone )` with no `declare`) throughout the rest of the script.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy As mentionned in https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question I edited the question.